# Android: Hide soft input keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I need to hide the soft keyboard  in response to clicking a button.
I saw some posts about this, and I tried it with:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText1.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

That worked well. But now I have two EditText views. How can I now hide the soft keyboard, no matter wich EditText is selected? I tried it also with

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText1.getWindowToken(), 0);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText2.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

, but that didn't worked...

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**
Found solution. Posted below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply you dont need to point specific view. Im using this and works :)

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to not get the window token from the EditText, but from the buton wich hides the keyboard itselfs:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(hideKeyboardButton.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

You can "play" with the parameter to achieve whatever you want. 
Hope this helped!

Comment: Not exactly what I was searching for, but thank you anyways! :)